# Не работают горячие клавиши на русской раскладке в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, hotkeys

Обновился на `Ubuntu 20.04` с `19.10`. Отвалились любые горячие клавиши на русской раскладке. Кто знает как лечить?

Comment: Ibus попробуй удалить

Comment: @eri Не помогло(

Comment: Такая же фигня, ищу решения, пока безуспешно

Comment: @SHKEd Если найдешь решения - буду благодарен за ссылочку. Бомбит немного конечно, шел 2020 год, все еще надо страдать и решать такие базовые косяки :(

Comment: @SHKEd внезапно нашел решение, посмотри ответ

Answer (score 1):

Баг чинится если отключить в gnome tweak tools вот этот флаг
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]